# Meaning of "partial" in "Partial Data Report" as required by ASME

Tags: word-meaning, terminology

I've been translating a document and came across the phrase "partial data report". It is almost certainly used there in the sense implied by [ASME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASME).

I asked on a translators' forum and one guy came up with a URL of a [form for this report](http://www.asme.org/wwwasmeorg/media/ResourceFiles/AboutASME/Who%20We%20Are/BPVC%20Resources/Section_I/BPVC_I_P-4.pdf).

Am I right to assume that the adjective "partial" here stands for "related to parts" and not for "incomplete"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen "partial" used this way, but from the form it is clear that it refers to parts. I seriously doubt that "incomplete" data would be certified.

According to the definition of [partial](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/partial):

> 2) of, being, or affecting only a part; not complete or total"

the referenced "parts" are part of (a component of) the complete unit. And the certification "affects the status of a part".

But I agree that it is ambiguous, and it could be read as "incomplete" data.

Comment: It turned out it's a report on a particular part (say, a vessel is a part of a flange heater). Technical language is tough.

Answer (score 0):

This [document](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=s8F83TJ6jloC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=partial%20data%20report&source=bl&ots=K-slgnVmAM&sig=vICseMvWQfvsrr-0ERDrJzYY3I4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC0972mNbMAhXEPxoKHWlsA50Q6AEIMTAJ#v=onepage&q=partial%20data%20report&f=false) suggests that a manufacturer must provide a form U-1 for tests on a complete pressure vessel and a U2 form with a **partial data report** for a self contained heat exchanger bundle.

As the form U2 must be attached to the form U1, one could argue that the **partial data report** is either part of the data for the complete pressure vessel, or complete data on a sub-component of the pressure vessel.